# How to get go back two pages in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript, I have a page A, which has a link to page B. B has javascript that redirects to another page C via `window.location.href=""`. The problem is in IE 10/11, if i click back on page C, it goes back to page B, which redirects back to page C again. I want it so that it goes back to page A.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can add your own back button, which will go back two pages instead of one, and set its `onclick` attribute to be:

```
window.history.go(-2)
```

That will bypass the redirect page.

EDIT: As [@NelsonTeixeira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752520/nelson-teixeira) clarified, you can create your own button, and label it whatever you'd like.  For example:

```
<button onclick="window.history.go(-2)">Back</button>
```

Comment: I can't add my own back button.

Comment: He's not telling you to add another back button. He's telling you to put that code on the onclick event.

Comment: @omega I've clarified the answer to hopefully eliminate any confusion.

Comment: There is no button. I'm talking about the native browser back button. There is no onclick handler for it.

Comment: @omega Sorry, I should have been more specific. You can create your own button for the user to click, to send them back the correct amount of pages. If you just want to do it using the native Back button, you might want to look into using `location.hash`.  You can find a good guide to that here: [http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-manage-the-back-button-with-javascript/](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-manage-the-back-button-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blindly sending visitor of B to C you should use document.referrer to check where the user is coming from .

If referrer is A then goto C 
else goto A or if referrer is C goto A

[Document.referrer at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

For example, you will put this code in page B:

```
var ref = document.referrer;

if(ref.includes("pageC.html")){
    window.location.href="pageA.html";
}
else{
    window.location.href="pageC.html";
}
```